# Applying different XSLT templates depending on parameter

Tags: php, xslt

I want to apply different templates depending on different parameters. I not sure how to achieve this with xslt. I use the setParameter() in php to set the parameter. Can I use param to do this in the xsl and if so, how? Or is there some better way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="name"></xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="1">

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="2">

  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use different modes. In XSLT 1.0, you'd need a switch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="name"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$name='1'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mode1"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mode2"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="mode1">
    ...
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="mode2">
    ...
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0, it's possible to use parameters in a matching pattern, like

```
<xsl:template match="*[$test='1']">

</xsl:template>
```

but using modes would be the better choice, too. Be aware that you need to set the proper mode whenever you define a template or are calling `<apply-templates>`. If you have templates that are common to both your processing branches, then you can give them a mode name like `common` or leave them modeless. Once again, be aware that they will only be applied when using `<apply-templates>` with the proper mode (be it `mode1`, `mode2`, `common` or no mode).

Answer (score 0):

yup, you can use something like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('test.xml');

# LOAD XML FILE
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$XML = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$XML->loadXML($xml);

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$XSL->load('test.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
```

With this you can use any xslt you want without adding anything to the source XML. You need to have PHP DOM enabled and `--enable-libxml` in your PHP install.

The idea is: instead of changing the XSLT to do more stuff, implement multiple smaller XSLT and choose the one you need.

If you want to pass parameters to the XSLT using PHP you need to do it like this:

```
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->setParameter('', 'owner', $name);
```